# How to allow only certain files in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, filter

I'd like to filter access to certain files in apache. I want only CGI access.
So I tried putting in vhost file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.cgi$">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "."> # All other files
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

But the latter overrides it all.

Thanks

Comment: Does swapping the tags work?

Comment: nope............

Comment: Probably a serverfault question..

Answer (score 1):

I have tried on my testing platform and it should work. The key point is you need to deny all access to the directory you would like to take control, e.g. **protected**:

```
<Directory "/protected">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

With this setting, all files from your **protected** folder is not accessible. Then you can allow CGI access as follow:

```
<FilesMatch "\.cgi$">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

You should be able to run any CGI file now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to swap the values in your Order directive as follows:

```
<FilesMatch "\.cgi$">
 Order Deny,Allow
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "."> # All other files
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

This will by default deny all access for all files. Any file ending in .cgi will then be allowed. See the [documentation on the Order directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way in an .htaccess file to allow only HTML files to be served, providing 403 HTTP status codes for files like .txt, etc.:

```
# By default, deny access to files like .txt,.json
Order Allow,Deny

# Allow access to default index and HTML files
<FilesMatch "(^$)|(\.(gif|jpg|png|html|php|css|js)$)">
    Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
```